# Redis desktop dependency on libicu52 for ubuntu12.04

Tags: redis, ubuntu-12.04

I want to use a redis browser and I found `redis-desktop-manager`.
(http://redisdesktop.com/download)

I downloaded a deb file but it requested `libicu52`.

Frist. How can I install this one in `Ubuntu12.04`.

Second. I found later that it seems to support `Ubuntu version 14+`.

Would I run this on `12.04` version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably compile `redis-desktop-manager` from source on your system, using the libicu* version that comes with 12.04.  I would also consider upgrading: 12.04 is no longer supported, has been replaced as an LTS by 14.04 and it generally far behind.

FWIW `redis-desktop-manager` installs and runs fine on my 15.04 and 15.10 systems.

Answer (score 5):

For the dependency of `libicu52` Redis Desktop fail to install. You can follow bellow step:

## Step 1: To download the libicu52 file. Run the command in the terminal:

```
   wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu52_52.1-8ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
```

## Step 2: Install  libicu52 by executing this command:

```
   dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-8ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
```

Now, Attempt once again to install `redis-desktop-manager` client from debian file, I believe now everything is fine ;)

FYI, `redis-desktop-manager` installs and runs perfectly on my 15.10 systems.

Comment: Worked great on Ubuntu Mate 1.10.2 Thanks!

Comment: My ubuntu 15.10 came with libicu55 pre-installed. But this made redis desktop install perfectly.